# Upload File attached to FileUpload Control to FTP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a file that is attached to a FileUpload control to a folder that is created in FTP. The Folder is getting created without issue but I can't seem to upload the file.

It seems as though my filepath to the source file is incorrect in the line `String filePath = Server.MapPath("~" + @"\" + nameToGiveFolder);` I have tried multiple variations of the file path but cannot seem to get the file uploaded.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string ftphost = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myHost"].ToString();
    string u = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["u"].ToString();
    string p = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["p"].ToString();
    string nameToGiveFolder = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString().Substring(0, FileUpload1.FileName.ToString().LastIndexOf("."));
    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + "/" + nameToGiveFolder;
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(u, p);
    FtpWebResponse CreateFolderResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            Label1.Text = "Has File";
            String filePath = Server.MapPath("~" + @"\" +  nameToGiveFolder);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "No File";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx). to get the file name

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}/{1}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName), FileUpload1.FileName)));
```

Note that you need to give the file name as well, if the file name is `abc.jpg`, above code try to create folder under your root of the web side called `abc` and save the file inside that folder with file name `abc.jpg`

i think your problem of line `String filePath = Server.MapPath("~" + @"\" + nameToGiveFolder);` is only having folder path at the end. when you call `FileUpload1.SaveAs` you need to have full file path.

### Update

You get the error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path

because you don't have directory with the name of file name. I'm not where exactly you want to put the file. if you going to put the file in new directory, you need to create that directory first.

```
var folderpath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)));


System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath); 

FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folderpath, FileUpload1.FileName));
```

Comment: THanks for the response! When I try do this, I get the error <b>System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\me\mySolution\me\toUpperCase\toUpperCase.txt'. </b>

Comment: Tried modifying the file path a little bit and got this error message (at least it's something different):  System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): 'ftp:/444.444.444.444/toUpperCase/toUpperCase.txt' is not a valid virtual path.